# Gunicorn ModuleNotFound : No module named 'core' when Deployment Django

Tags: django, gunicorn, wsgi

I try to deployment my apps.

So when i try to run this command

```
gunicorn -c conf/gunicorn_config.py core.wsgi
```

Error : ModuleNotFound : No module named 'core'

This is my directory

- home/uletin
  --- **conf**
  --------- **...** 
  --------- **gunicorn_config.py** 
  --- **env**
  --- **graduates**
  ------...
  ------**core**
  ------------ ...
  ------------ **settings.py**
  ------------ **wsgi.py**
  ------------ ...
  ------**manage.py**
  ------**static**

in gunicorn_config.py like this

```
command = '/home/uletin/env/bin/gunicorn'
pythonpath = 'home/uletin/graduates'
bind = '165.22.98.56:8000'
workers = 3
```

Comment: Do you also have a 'graduates' folder in the directory? When you first start a django project, it would have created another folder with the same name as the project. I don't see that in your directory structure

Comment: i'm rename the first directory to 'graduates', when first start a django project i name it 'core'

Comment: and i create github project name 'graduates', and i'm push app core, manage.py etc to project 'graduates'. @OmarSiddiqui

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is the fact that the project name, and the main app inside it have different names.

You said that you've renamed the main folder to `graduates`. What I would suggest is either change the name back to `core` and then try executing your command. It should work. Gunicorn expects that the wsgi.py file will be present in a folder that has the same name as the project directory. If you're going to be updating the name back to core, you'll need to update your *pythonpath* variable as well

The other thing you can try, if you want to keep the name `graduates` is, rename the inner `core` folder to `graduates` as well, and modify your command so that it says this:

```
gunicorn -c conf/gunicorn_config.py graduates.wsgi
```

Comment: i'm rename main folder graduates to 'core' and update pythonpath in gunicorn_config.py to 'home/uletin/core'. its still not working

Comment: Can you tell me what the value for the `WSGI_APPLICATION` variable is in your settings.py file?

Comment: In the settings.py like this. WSGI_APPLICATION = 'core.wsgi.application'